# error: Illegal modifier for parameter

Tags: java, static, int, public, final

I was using these lines of code...

```
public static final int WIDTH = 240;
public static final int HEIGHT = 350;
public static final int SCALE = 2;
```

but I always got these errors ...

```
Illegal modifier for parameter WIDTH; only final is permitted
Illegal modifier for parameter HEIGHT; only final is permitted
Illegal modifier for parameter SCALE; only final is permitted
```

Comment: Where did you try to define those?

Comment: write entire code or class

Comment: @Real - or at least the relevant pieces that show the error

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to add "public" and "static" modifiers inside a method.  You can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that you are trying to use `public` and `static` on local variable declarations or method parameter declarations.  Locals / parameters can only be `final`.

You can only use `public` and `static` on class members (or similar).